# using a timer to count pulses on STM32F7

Tags: timer, counter, stm32

I have a question about using a timer to count pulses form a encoder (only one pin) I don't care about the direction.

I'm tryning to use Timer 3, but I'm not sure how to set it up in CubeMx.

[picture and text](https://community.st.com/message/174554-using-a-timer-to-count-pulses-on-stm32f7)

I start it with: 
HAL_TIM_Base_Start( mpEncoderTim );

And read with: 
count = mpEncoderTim->Instance->CNT;

Hope anyone of you, have done this before, so you can give me a hint

thanks in advance and best regards
panduro..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I found the error, the timer period was set to 0, so the timer would never count higher than 0 :-(

best regards..

Answer (score 0):

I'v had some kind of similar issue with stepper motor. I'v made a stepper driver code for (DRV8825, A4899 chips) , code is iRQ based and  with maths for motor acceleration, speed and etc. But I had to test if it is accurate, so I had to count steps.
For testing case I configured concrete pin  as ETR(external trigger input) - it is input pin,my stepper output pin goes to that input,(as for sure goes to motor too). And each rising or lowering edge(depends on configuration) generates an irq, so at irq I can set counter of steps, in your case pulses.

I am not familiar with cubeMX stuff, most of the time I write directly to register or using old SPL(standard peripherial drivers). I will show how it works with SPL as it should be more readable for cubeMX users.

**Anyway I just try to show basic idea how to do it.This concrete code works on STM32f030**

Firstly configure input pin (read datasheet just few pins can work as external triggers and with concrete timers)

```
void digital_input_config (void){

    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12; 
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;  
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_10MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP; 
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP; 
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_2);
}
```

Now you need a timer configuration, each timer has different pins with ETR, so it depends on your STM32 MCU.You have to read data sheet accurately.

```
void enable_capture_TIM1(void){
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_ETRClockMode2Config(TIM1,TIM_ExtTRGPSC_DIV_NONE,TIM_ExtTRGPolarity_NonInverted,0x00);
    TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM1,TIM_TS_ETRF);
    TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM1,TIM_SlaveMode_Trigger);

    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = 0;
    NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM1, TIM_IT_Trigger, ENABLE);
}
```

And at the IRQ you can do pulse counting.

```
void TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler(void){

    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM1, TIM_IT_Trigger) != RESET) {
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1, TIM_IT_Trigger);
        PulseCNT++;
    }

}
```

I'v tested this code with pulse generator and it's really accurate, it can be used for pulse count, or frequency measuring.